# How can I list all hidden methods for ALTabletService and the other services?

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

I discovered that there is `ALTabletService` methods that is not listed on the official [Aldebaran ALTabletService API](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html). For example if you initialize: `tabletService = self.session().service("ALTabletService")` then you can call:

- `tabletService._installApk("path_to_apk")`
- `tabletService._uninstallApps()`
- `tabletService._stopApk("package_name")`
- `tabletService._openSettings()`

How can I the list of all "private" methods the `AL` serices?

I guess I can find the binaries and then I can try to decompile the files, but I suppose there is an easier way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to SSH onto a robot and use qicli - see [the doc here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/libqi/guide/qicli.html).

For example, try `qicli info ALTabletService --show-doc --hidden`.

Note that usually methods are hidden for good reasons, so you should not write code that depends on them; they may disappear in future versions.

Comment: I had read this documentation but I didn't see this `--hidden` option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `.getMethodList`, it should also list hidden methods.

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but unfortunately for some reason it does not work for me.